# Does a SSL certificate created using rsa:2048 use an SHA-2 cryptographic hash algorithm?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, openssl, rsa

Google is trying to phase out use of SSL certificates using SHA1 hashing algorithm.  As  result I want to create a SHA2 compliant self signed certificate.  I understand the SHA is a hashing algorithm, whilst RSA is an encryption algorithm. I found the following command for producing the key and certificate pair:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Will this produce a certificate using SHA-2 hashing algorithm?

After deploying the certificate, Chrome reports the following:

[image: Chrome browser report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have solved the issue.  The command I have been using uses openssl's default hashing algorithm which is SHA-1.  To create a SHA-2 hashed certificate one must specify an SHA-2 option.  In this case I chose to use SHA-256. Following is the updated command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Comment: If you add the option `-x509`, you get a self-signed certificate right away without having to use another *openssl* command.

Answer (score 3):

The hash algorithm used by the certificate issuer to sign a certificate request is unrelated to the certificate request itself. That means the CA might use SHA-2 for the 2048 bit key, but it might also use SHA-1. It might even re-sign the same certificate which was once signed with SHA-1 now with SHA-2.
Currently most (all?) public CA use SHA-2 because SHA-1 is phased out for security reasons.

In your case you use the `openssl req` command to create not only a certificate request but also sign it, i.e. create a self-signed certificate. Modern versions of `openssl` will use SHA-2 to sign this new certificate by default, older versions SHA-1. To enforce SHA-2 as the signature algorithm use the `-sha256` argument.

Comment: In this case I am creating my own self-signed certificate.  So no CA involved.  I want to be able to create my own SHA-2 signed certificate. I am not sure if the command provided in OP will do this or not.

Comment: @Benjen: I did not see that you create a self-signed certificate. See edited post for more information.